# Conseguir el ultimo dia del mes, sí cae en sábado o domingo, que me diga el lunes

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día.

Estoy haciendo 2 funciones. Antes de explicar les muestro la tabla de resultados que espero obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, el **FIN** de cada periodo debe ser el ultimo día del mes, pero, si ese día cae en sábado o domingo, se pasa al proximo día hábil, como en el caso del periodo 2 y 5, que el fin del mes cae en sábado 31, y el proximo día hábil es el lunes 2.

El **INICIO** de cada periodo es el fin del periodo mas 1 día.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda brindada.

***UPDATE*** - Agrego una función que tengo que me regresa el **ultimo día del mes**, asi normal, funciona. Tambien agrego una cosulta que me regresa el **primer día habil de un mes**.

Es lo que tengo, en base a ellas estoy intentando combinarlas para sacar lo que busco.

```
----- ULTIMO DIA DEL MES -----------
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes]
(
    @nMes       int,
    @nEjercicio int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @nDias          int,
            @dFecha         datetime,
            @dFechaUlima    datetime


    IF @nMes = 12
    BEGIN
        SET @nMes = 1
        SET @nEjercicio = @nEjercicio + 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @nMes = @nMes + 1
    END

    SET @dFecha = RTRIM( LTRIM( STR( @nEjercicio))) + 
                  CASE WHEN LEN( @nMes) = 1 THEN  '0' + RTRIM( LTRIM( STR( @nMes))) ELSE RTRIM( LTRIM( STR( @nMes))) END 
                  + '01'

    SET @dFechaUlima = DATEADD( DD, -1, @dFecha)


    RETURN ISNULL( @dFechaUlima, '')
END






--------- PRIMER DíA HáBIL DE UN MES --------------
SELECT CASE WHEN Datename(dw, Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') + 1, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000')) = 'Saturday' 
                            THEN Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') + 3, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') 
                        WHEN Datename(dw, Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') + 1, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000')) = 'Sunday' 
                            THEN Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') + 2, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') 
                        ELSE Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') + 1, '2019-12-12 00:00:00.000') 
                END
```

**UPDATE: Captura del resultado de enero en sistema final. Funciona, internamente ya vimos que no correcto, pero al final si regresa los dias bien.** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, podrias poner las tablas que tienes y los datos que llevas al  momento o lo que has intentado para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final tal vez no me explique bien, pero logre resolverlo.

Terminé haciendo la siguiente consulta, ahora la volvere función, para que reciba un dateTime.

Total, ya me regresa el inicio y fin del periodo como lo necesito, sin importar que año es, si es año bisiesto, si el inicio o fin de mes cae en fin de semana, etc.

```
select (CASE 
                    WHEN Datename(dw, (CASE 
                    WHEN Datename(dw, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')-1, YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')) ) = 'Saturday' 
                    THEN Dateadd(dd, 2, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')-1, YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'))) 
                    WHEN Datename(dw, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')-1, YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')) ) = 'Sunday' 
                    THEN Dateadd(dd, 1, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')-1, YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')))
                ELSE dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')-1, YEAR( GETDATE())) 
            END) ) = 'Monday' 
                    THEN Dateadd(dd, 1, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Primero_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'))) 
                ELSE dbo.FIDA_Dias_Primero_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( GETDATE())) 
            END) as INICIO ,--Fin de DateAdd
            (CASE 
                    WHEN Datename(dw, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')) ) = 'Saturday' 
                    THEN Dateadd(dd, 2, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'))) 
                    WHEN Datename(dw, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')) ) = 'Sunday' 
                    THEN Dateadd(dd, 1, dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000')))
                ELSE dbo.FIDA_Dias_Ultimo_Mes( MONTH( '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'), YEAR( GETDATE())) 
            END) as FIN
```

Disculpen el código desorganizado. Prometo dejarlo bien.

Comment: Tu solución genera errores cuando usas enero como fecha. Para el último día del mes, puedes usar EOMONTH() y también podrías usar DATEFROMPARTS() para obtener una fecha usando el mes y año (a partir de la versión 2012)

Comment: ¡Ah canijos! , pues, ¿Que error te salio? A mi aparentemente me tira los dias correctos, de hecho me avente una tabla en excel con los días esperados de cada periodo y hasta ahora no me ha fallado (Y mas importante aun, nadie se ha quejado de ello jejeje). Voy a subir un update con una captura de mi consulta corriendo con enero del 2020.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón Luis, vaya... no lo habia notado, gracias por la aclaración. El año, no aumenta. Cuando lo corrija comparto la consulta.

Comment: Aunque, si me resuelve el problema. Internamente ya verifique gracias a tu ayuda que no lo hace bien, pero al final (como los dias se la pasa a otra funcion) si regresa el resultado esperado. Subire un update con captura.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí dejo un cálculo que funciona para calcular suficientes meses. La primer parte del código hasta la expresión de cteTally es simplemente para generar una columna de números consecutivos que genera las filas sin necesidad de ciclos o cursores. La siguiente expresión calcula el inicio y final de cada mes. Por último, hacemos un cálculo para recorrer las fechas según el día de la semana en la que termine el mes anterior.

```
DECLARE @Fecha datetime = '20190702';

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4
),
ctePeriodos AS(
    SELECT N + 1 AS Periodo,
           DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, @Fecha) + N , 0)  AS Inicio,
           DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF( MM, -1, @Fecha) + N, 0) -1 AS Fin
    FROM cteTally
)
SELECT Periodo,
       CASE WHEN Periodo = 1 THEN @Fecha
            WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, 0, Inicio) % 7 = 0 THEN DATEADD( DD, 1, Inicio) --Si es lunes recorremos un día
            WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, 0, Inicio) % 7 = 6 THEN DATEADD( DD, 2, Inicio) --Si es domingo recorremos dos días
            --WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, 0, Inicio) % 7 = 5 THEN DATEADD( DD, 3, Inicio) --Esto era para recorrer en sábado pero creo que no se recorre si el mes termina en viernes
            ELSE Inicio END AS Inicio, 
         CASE   WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, 0, Fin) % 7 = 6 THEN DATEADD( DD, 1, Fin) --Si es domingo recorremos un día
                WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, 0, Fin) % 7 = 5 THEN DATEADD( DD, 2, Fin) --Si es sábado recorremos dos días
                ELSE Fin END Fin
FROM ctePeriodos
```

Answer (score 2):

Anexo otra forma de hacerlo.

Este se puede volver una función recibe el día de inicio y los periodos que tendrá en este caso mando el 2 de julio para formar lo que requieres y 5 como periodo para que se vea como lo necesitas.

```
DECLARE @Inicio DATE ='20190702' --Dia de inicio que definamos
DECLARE @Levl INT=5 --Cuandos periodos se crearan en este caso 5 para hacer el ejemplo que muestras
--creamos un CTE Recursivo
;WITH  CTE_RECURSIVE AS (
SELECT   @Inicio AS Inicio,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Inicio)+1,0)-1 AS DATE))=7  THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Inicio)+1,0)-1 AS DATE)) 
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Inicio)+1,0)-1 AS DATE))=1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Inicio)+1,0)-1 AS DATE))
    ELSE CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Inicio)+1,0)-1 AS DATE) END AS Fin,
     1 AS [Level]
UNION ALL --Aqui lo volvemos recursivo
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin) AS Inicio,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin))+1,0)-1 AS DATE))=7 /*Cuando es 7 es sabado entonces agregamos 2 dias*/ THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin))+1,0)-1 AS DATE)) 
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin))+1,0)-1 AS DATE))=1 /*Cuando es 1 es domingo entonces agregamos 1 dia*/ THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin))+1,0)-1 AS DATE))
    ELSE CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(DAY,1,Fin))+1,0)-1 AS DATE)/*Si no el dia tal cual es*/ END AS Fin
,CTE_RECURSIVE.Level+1 as [Level]
FROM CTE_RECURSIVE
WHERE Level<@Levl--aqui le decimos cuantos en este caso 5
)

SELECT Level AS Periodo,
CAST(DAY(Inicio) AS varchar(2))+'-'+DATENAME(MONTH,Inicio)+'-'+CAST(YEAR(Inicio) as varchar(5)) AS Inicio,
CAST(DAY(Fin) AS varchar(2))+'-'+DATENAME(MONTH,Fin)+'-'+CAST(YEAR(Fin) as varchar(5)) AS Fin
FROM CTE_RECURSIVE
```

De esta forma no se declara nada, solo se hace uso de un CTE recursivo para calcular lo que necesites.

Saludos.